# Is there a way to record changes in a log file in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, logging

I'm very new to powershell. I am working exporting csv files from a database that gets updated periodically. For example, it will output csv files like Test1.csv and the contents for the first run will be

Test1.csv

```
 111,1,111
 222,1,222
 333,1,333
```

if the script were to run the second time, the output of the same Test1.csv file will be

Test1.csv

```
 111,1,111
 222,1,222
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to compare the old Test1.csv and the new Test1.csv and log the difference?

This is code I have:

```
$location= "C:\Location"
$path = Test-Path $location -IsValid
If($path -eq $True)
{
$checkFile = "C:\Location\Test1.csv"
if(Test-Path $checkFile -PathType leaf)
{
$before = import-csv Test1.csv
}
else
{
  Write-Output "No Exist"
}

# Run some code here that may change Test1.csv

$location= "C:\Location"
$path = Test-Path $location -IsValid
If($path -eq $True)
{
$checkFile = "C:\Location\Test1.csv"
if(Test-Path $checkFile -PathType leaf)
{
$after= import-csv Test1.csv
}
else
{
  Write-Output "No Exist"
}


$after = import-csv Test1.csv
$removed,$added = @(Compare-Object $before $after).where({$_.SideIndicator -eq '<='},'Split')
if ($removed) {
    "The following lines were removed: "
    $removed.InputObject
}
if ($added) {
    "The following lines were added: "
    $added.InputObject
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a hint as to what's not working with your attempt?

Comment: @zdan Yes. When I run the script, the old import are not begin saved and the log file produce blank results

Comment: Just use a FIleSystemWatcher and when an event (create, modify, etc.) fires read the file again using the Compare-Object cmdlet to see the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Current Script Results

It looks like you are really close already.  I had to modify your compare code a little bit to get it to work.  I added `-Header "A","B","C"` because your sample input has duplicate values and no headers (which causes an error).

After doing running the compare section on your sample input, I got this:

```
The following lines were removed: 

ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
------- ------- -------
333     1       333
```

I ran it again by adding `444,1,444` (in addition to adding the 3 line back) and got this:

```
The following lines were added: 

ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
------- ------- -------
444     1       444
```

It sounds like you want to be able to see something that shows all the lines that were added and all the lines that were removed in one output.  To do that, we need to make the comparison more complex and run the command on all the returned values.

### Updated Script

In order to correctly compare objects, the `Compare-Object` cmdlet needs to know what properties to compare.  To do that, we'll specify them with `-Property`.  As noted in the above section, I added the header argument to `Import-Csv`, so those will be automatically converted to the object properties.

```
$comparison = Compare-Object $before $after -Property A,B,C
```

There was nothing wrong with your logic to get the array of added and removed lines, but this is much more readable in my opinion:

```
$removed = @($comparison | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' })
$added = @($comparison | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' })
```

We don't need to display the entire object, because we've already broken the lists down to added and removed.  So, we'll only select the properties we are using (`-Property A,B,C`).  PowerShell likes to "help" you display things nicely, so sometimes it will take output with the same objects and display them in the same table.  We need to override that default behavior by forcing it to use `Format-Table`.

```
if($removed)
{
    Write-Host "The following lines were removed:"
    $removed | Select -Property A,B,C | Format-Table
}

if($added)
{
    Write-Host "The following lines were added:"
    $added | Select -Property A,B,C | Format-Table
}
```

### Sample Test1.csv - "Before"

```
111,1,111
222,1,222
333,1,333
444,1,444
BBB,1,BBB
```

### Sample Test2.csv - "After"

```
111,1,111
222,1,222
444,1,444
AAA,1,AAA
BBB,1,BBB
CCC,1,CCC
DDD,1,DDD
```

### New Script Results

```
The following lines were removed:

A   B C  
-   - -  
333 1 333


The following lines were added:

A   B C  
-   - -  
AAA 1 AAA
CCC 1 CCC
DDD 1 DDD
```

### Full Script

```
$before = import-csv Test1.csv -Header "A","B","C"
$after = import-csv Test2.csv -Header "A","B","C"

$comparison = Compare-Object $before $after -Property A,B,C

$removed = @($comparison | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '<=' })
$added = @($comparison | Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '=>' })

if($removed)
{
    Write-Host "The following lines were removed:"
    $removed | Select -Property A,B,C | Format-Table
}

if($added)
{
    Write-Host "The following lines were added:"
    $added | Select -Property A,B,C | Format-Table
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please mark it as the answer if you think it fully answers your question.